# jQuery remove input value in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID = "rpQuestion8" runat = "server" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddCounty" runat = "server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <input type = "hidden" id = "hidSurveyCustomerAreaID" runat = "server" value = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "SurveyCustomerAreaID")%>' />
                            </td>
                              <td>
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radStillStandHuntMethod" text = "Still/Stand" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8HuntMethod"/>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radDogHuntMethod" text = "Dog" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8HuntMethod"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID = "txtDaysHunted" runat = "server" Width = "50" text  = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "DaysHunted")%>'/>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID = "cvNumDays" runat = "server" ControlToValidate = "txtDaysHunted" Operator = "DataTypeCheck" Type = "Integer" Text = "*" ErrorMessage = "Please enter a whole number for Days Hunted." />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radYesUnprocessedFood" text = "Yes" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8UnprocessedFood" />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radNoUnprocessedFood" text = "No" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8UnprocessedFood" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID = "txtNumSeen" runat = "server" Width = "50"  text  = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "NumberSeen")%>' />
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID = "cvBearsSeen" runat = "server" ControlToValidate = "txtNumSeen" Operator = "DataTypeCheck" Type = "Integer" Text = "*" ErrorMessage = "Please enter a whole number for Number of Bears Seen." />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radYes" text = "Yes" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8Harvest" />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:radiobutton id = "radNo" text = "No" runat = "server" GroupName = "Question8Harvest" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script src="../../../Javascript/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ddCountyChange(sender) {
            if (sender.value === "") {
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").val('');
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").prop('checked', false);
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("label").css("color", "#cccccc");
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").val('');
            } else {
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").removeAttr('disabled');
                $(sender).parent().siblings().find("label").css("color", "#000000");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I want to be able to remove the value of the hidden input (id = "hidSurveyCustomerAreaID"). the jQuery code above does that for all the inputs in the repeater except for (id = "hidSurveyCustomerAreaID").

Comment: Have you tried `<asp:HiddenField>` insted of `input`?

Comment: Seeing the hidSurveyCustomerAreaID is a server control (runat=server) the actual ID might be different then what you expect. It could be ctrl0_hidSurveyCustomerAreaID or something.

Comment: @Null  
I did, It does the same thing HtmlHiddenInput does

Comment: @FrankWitte That's true, but the JQuery code is not calling it by the ID. `find("input")` finds controls by the type not the ID.

Comment: What is the code behind of this page? Is there an example (runnable) project where we can see what happens?
It could be that the autopostback of the ddCounty (re)fills the value again and such. But it is hard to guess without working code.

Comment: Try this 
`$("<%= hidSurveyCustomerAreaID.ClientID %>").val("");`

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the JQuery code:

```
$(sender).parent().find("input").val('');
```

This accesses the input that's inside the same `td` that the dropdownlist is in.

```
function ddCountyChange(sender) {
        if (sender.value === "") {
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").val('');
            $(sender).parent().find("input").val('');
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").prop('checked', false);
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("label").css("color", "#cccccc");
        } else {
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("input").removeAttr('disabled');
            $(sender).parent().siblings().find("label").css("color", "#000000");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good find (pun intended ;) I missed that you were only accessing the sibling TDs and not TD the dropdown resides in.
Because find() will get all children you could also perform the find on the TR and get 'em all in one go instead two calls:
`var inputs = $(sender).parent().parent().find('input');
inputs.val('');`

Comment: @FrankWitte exactly! I missed that too. Thank you for your time :)